# Regex for matching capitals

Tags: ruby, regex, match

```
 def normalized?

    matches = match(/[^A-Z]*/)
    return matches.size == 0

  end
```

This is my function operating on a string, checking wether a string contains only uppercase letters. It works fine ruling out non matches, but when i call it on a string like `"ABC"` it says no match, because apparently `matches.size` is 1 and not zero. There seems to be an empty element in it or so.

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: If your version of Ruby supports `\p{Lu}`, you always want to use that or `[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]` instead.  `[A-Z]` is one of those code-smell anti-patterns to be studiously avoided in code working with any text more modern than punch-cards.

Comment: Okay and why is that preferable? Does it outperform [A-Z] in speed?

Comment: @Samuel - To avoid the unicode crusaders, specify you only care to identify lines than contain letters [A-Z] if you do so.

Comment: Samuel: If correctness is of no importance, I can make anything run infinitely fast. So what? It isn’t that [A-Z] is slow; it’s that it’s wrong. `\p{Lu}` is better, although it still misses 42 uppercase code points.

Comment: I guess the \p{Lu} also works for letter like Ä etc? In my case though i strictly only support the letters A to Z, so im wondering isn't it faster to use only A-Z in my case?

Comment: @Samuel - If you specifically intend to just match A-Z, using unicode class (like \p{Lu}) will produce errors. So be sure thats what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchData#size` returns the number of capturing groups in the regex plus one, so that `md[i]` will access a valid group iff `i < md.size`. So the value returned by `size` only depends on the regex, not the matched string, and will never be 0.

You want `matches.to_s.size` or `matches[0].size`.

Comment: Thanks, do you advice me to keep my regex?

Comment: @Samuel: I'd go with mway's regex as it's more natural to say "the string contains only characters from A-Z" than to say "the string does not contain any characters not from A-Z".

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is wrong - if you want it to match ONLY uppercase strings, use `/^[A-Z]+$/`.

Comment: Okay, could you also tell me why it is wong, please?

Comment: Sure - you have a carat (`^`) inside the group (`[]`) which means NOT `A-Z`, and the asterisk means it could match nothing at all.  So we throw an end delimiter (`$`) on the end of the regex and change `*` to `+` to ensure that the string is at least 1 character long.

Comment: @mway: I think he's quite aware of what his regex does. That's why he tries to check whether the match was empty. If it was, then the string only contains capital letters. That might be an over-complicated way of doing this, but if `MatchData#size` did what he thought it did, it would be perfectly correct.

Comment: Yeah it's like he says, but thank you for providing an alternative, more logical regex :)

Comment: +1 for correct answer. @Samuel - this is not an alternative, its the only correct answer. There is no other regex that positively matches A-Z only.

Comment: @mway: I’m afraid your statement, and your regex, are both wrong. You cannot match only uppercase strings that way.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, you can, if your string is expected to contain only A-Z.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is incorrect. `/[^A-Z]*/` means "match zero or more characters that are not between `A` and `Z`, anywhere in the string". The string `ABC` has zero characters that are not between `A` and `Z`, so it matches the regular expression.

Change your regular expression to `/^[^A-Z]+$/`. This means "match one or more characters that are not between `A` and `Z`, and make sure every character between the beginning and end of the string are not between `A` and `Z`". Then the string `ABC` will not match, and then you can check `matches[0].size` or whatever, as per sepp2k's answer.

Comment: If he has a regex which does not match, he can most certainly **not** check `matches[0].size` as `matches` might be `nil`. The whole point of his current approach is that the regex will always match and he's checking whether it matched the empty string or something more substantial.

Answer (score 2):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180>   def normalized? s
ruby-1.9.2-p180?>    s.match(/^[[:upper:]]+$/) ? true : false
ruby-1.9.2-p180?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180>  normalized? "asdf"
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p180>  normalized? "ASDF"
 => true
```

Answer (score 1):

This question needs a more clear answer. As [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) commented, I wish he would have answered. The "**Regex for matching capitals**" is to use:

```
/\p{Uppercase}/
```

As tchrist mentions "is distinct from the general category \p{Uppercase_Letter} aka \p{Lu}. That’s because there exist non-Letters that count as Uppercase"

Comment: So how would you answer this guy's question then? `\p{Uppercase}` is going to match a single upper case Unicode spectrum letter. He want's to insure the string is all _upper_ cased letters. I guess an easy fix would be to match a single `\P{Uppercase}` then fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in your regular expression means that it matches any number of non-uppercase characters, including zero. So it always matches everything. The fix is to remove the `*`, then it will fail to match a string containing only uppercase characters. (Although you would need a different test if zero-length strings are not permitted.)

Answer (score 0):

There is **only** 1 regular expression that defines a string with only and **All** capitals:

`def onlyupper(s)`
    `(s =~ /^[A-Z]+$/) != nil`
`end`

Truth table:

```
/[^A-Z]*/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  'asdf'     length  4
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  ''         length  0
 Testing  ''         matched  ''         length  0
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  '-='       length  2
--------
/[^A-Z]+/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  'asdf'     length  4
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  nil
 Testing  ''         matched  nil
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  '-='       length  2
--------
/^[^A-Z]*$/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  'asdf'     length  4
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  nil
 Testing  ''         matched  ''         length  0
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  nil
--------
/^[^A-Z]+$/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  'asdf'     length  4
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  nil
 Testing  ''         matched  nil
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  nil
--------
/^[A-Z]*$/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  nil
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  'HHH'      length  3
 Testing  ''         matched  ''         length  0
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  nil
--------
/^[A-Z]+$/:
 Testing  'asdf'     matched  nil
 Testing  'HHH'      matched  'HHH'      length  3
 Testing  ''         matched  nil
 Testing  '-=AAA'    matched  nil
--------
```

Comment: @tchrist Oh yeah, what is A-Z, I know its not a-z? Try to stay on topic which is A-Z !

Comment: Your function incorrectly pretends that `[A-Z]` somehow suffices to guarantee that something be entirely in uppercase: it misses ᴇ,ᴋ,Á,Æ,Þ,Ȝ,İ,Ə,Ⅻ,etc, **and that’s all still just in the Latin script!** A-Z is clearly wrong: *it misses 968 uppercase code points.* One must use `\p{Uppercase}` to guarantee that. Note that the derived binary property `\p{Uppercase}` is distinct from the general category `\p{Uppercase_Letter}` aka `\p{Lu}`. That’s because there exist non-Letters that count as Uppercase, like Roman numerals like  Ⅷ and circled letters like Ⓐ are both `\p{Uppercase}` but `\P{Lu}`.

Comment: The querent requested information on how to match uppercase.  Answer the question correctly.

Comment: I guess he didn't since he only cares to match A-Z. Question answered correctly.

Comment: Until you rename your function, it is lying when it says *onlyupper*. I have explained what only upper actually means.  What you have written is simply incorrect.

Comment: @tchris - Ok, I've had my attention drawn here for a downvote. It's 2017 now. Just looking over your comments a second. Let's be a little more clear here. First, in Unicode 8, backed by UCD there are now 1751 cp's for the _Uppercase_ property. I'm sure version 9 has more. Second, the difference between _Uppercase_ and _Lu_ is a net negative of 120 cp's _Lu_ doesn't have. I get that from my engine with _[^\P{Uppercase=Yes}\p{General_Category_Mask=Uppercase_Letter}]+_. Third and finally, engines don't supply this info, it is supplied by a backing database. The key note being fluidity ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know that the input string entirely consists of English uppercase letters, i.e. A-Z, then you must remove the Kleene Star as it will match before and after every single character in any input string (zero length match). The statement `!s[/[^A-Z]/]` tells you if there's no match of non-A-to-Z characters:

```
irb(main):001:0> def normalized? s
irb(main):002:1>     return !s[/[^A-Z]/]
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> normalized? "ABC"
=> true
irb(main):005:0> normalized? "AbC"
=> false
irb(main):006:0> normalized? ""
=> true
irb(main):007:0> normalized? "abc"
=> false
```

Comment: Taking away the `*` quantifier while still using a negagive A-Z class still matches the empty string when putting a `!` conditional on the match result. Empty string returns `true` when it does not really represent a string consisting of letters A-Z. See the truth table I posted above.

Comment: Its kind of the same as `!/[^A-Z]+/`

Comment: The empty string should definitively return `true` since @Samuel's requirement was _"checking wether a string contains only uppercase letters"_. The empty string _contains only uppercase letters_. The statement `!s[/[^A-Z]/]` tells you if there's no match of non-A-to-Z characters. It's a correct answer, given that _uppercase letters_ means A to Z.

Comment: @Staffan `The empty string contains only uppercase letters.` Lets test this theory `"" =~ /[A-Z]/`. Nope, the empty string contains only nothing.

Comment: @sln It's a question of definition, and we don't seem to agree. :-) I still claim that a _no characters string_ is a type of _uppercase only string_. To say it's not _uppercase only string_, we need at least one character that isn't _uppercase_ -- a counter proof. `/[A-Z]/` test if there's _at least one uppercase_, which is something different from _uppercase only_. However, this is a sub discussion. :-)

Comment: @Staffan If the empty string contains only A-Z letters, then it should positively match `/[A-Z]/` but it doesen't. Conversly, `"ABC" =~ /^$/` doesn't match, but we don't say "ABC" is the empty string. I don't think nothing can exist as a subset of everything, that would make `(nothing == something)` true. Nothing could be qualitatively beneficial, but its separate information in a test for something.